# Non-vanishing Sections in Canonical Line Bundle over Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I'm trying to understand why there are no non-vanishing sections in $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

We have the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^n$ given by $E:=\{(l, v) \in \mathbb{R}P^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}| v \in l\}$ with the map $\pi$ being just the projection on to the first coordinate and a section is just picking out vectors in $\pi^{-1}(l)$ for each $l\in \mathbb{R}P^n.$ $\pi^{-1}(l)$ is just $\mathbb{R}$, right? I then don't see what's wrong with having a non-vanishing section in $\mathbb{R}P^n$. I'd appreciate if someone could point out any mistakes I'm making or where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried to draw the picture when $n=1$?

Comment: Do you think every line bundle has a nowhere-zero section? That's not true. Only trivial line bundles admit a nowhere-zero section.

Comment: I knew of the result you mention (and its proof) , but I guess not going through - and drawing - examples before was my mistake. Thank you.